# Error installing mmmagic with npm, node-gyp rebuild fail

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I am trying to install `mmmagic` with `npm install` and continue to get this error.

I have tried multiple versions of `mmmagic` as well as using node v0.10.40 & node v0.12.7, and reinstalling `node-gyp`.

I have cleared npm cache and destroyed the `node_module` folder multiple times.

Any ideas?

```
make: *** [Release/magic.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/XXXX/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/Users/XXXX/.nvm/v0.10.40/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/XXXX/Desktop/EdvisorIO/JJJJ/node_modules/mmmagic
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.40
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! mmmagic@0.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mmmagic@0.3.16 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mmmagic package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mmmagic
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/XXXX/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node" "/Users/XXXX/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/XXXX/Desktop/EdvisorIO/JJJJ
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: On OS X 10.11 Thank for the response, but figured it out. Had to do with the an issue with OS X and Homebrew.
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/40653

Comment: We're seeing this error on Windows too...

Comment: There is a response on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408466/npm-installing-mmmagic-fails#39408466

Comment: I came here looking for the same problem, but I wasn't directly installing mmmagic, a dependency was. Turns out, changing the node version worked for me. I set it to 10.16.3 from 12.15.0 using `n`.