# npm installing mmmagic fails

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, mmmagic

I am attempting to install `mmmagic` however I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "mmmagic"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! mmmagic@0.4.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mmmagic@0.4.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the mmmagic package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs mmmagic
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mmmagic
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/learningbankapi/src/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried to run

```
npm install node-gyp rebuild
```

On its own however this did not resolve the problem.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I may fix it?

Comment: I think this may be because of a missing `node` symlink. Assuming you're on Ubuntu/Debian, you should be able to install the symlink by installing the `nodejs-legacy` package. Otherwise you can just install the symlink manually so that calling `node` points to `nodejs`. If that doesn't help, post the console output leading up to these 'npm ERR!' lines.

Comment: This worked please post it as a response for furture watchers

Comment: I came here looking for the same problem, but I wasn't directly installing mmmagic, a dependency was. Turns out, changing the node version worked for me. I set it to 10.16.3 from 12.15.0 using `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `node` symlink is missing. On Debian/Ubuntu you can add the symlink by installing the `nodejs-legacy` package. Otherwise you can just manually create a symlink to the `nodejs` executable.

Comment: how should I create a symlink to the nodejs executable?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed GCC to solve this problem

```sh
yum install gcc-c++ make
```

Because I reinstalled nodejs from nodesource and noticed that it reminded me:

```
...

## Checking for existing installations...

+ rpm -qa 'node|npm' | grep -v nodesource

## Run `sudo yum install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 10.x and npm.
## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
     sudo yum install gcc-c++ make
## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
     curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
     sudo yum install yarn
```